# Godot 3.1 Invalid get'index '16' (on base:Array)

Tags: arrays, godot

**Invalid get'index '16' (on base:Array).**

Hi Im getting the above message when the player attempts to moves outside of the 
array size (tile size). 
The error occurs on line 54:

```
grid[new_grid_pos.x][new_grid_pos.y] = ENTITY_TYPES.PLAYER
```

Im stuck on how to fix it.
regards
Jason

```
extends TileMap

var tile_size = get_cell_size()
var half_tile_size = tile_size / 2

enum ENTITY_TYPES {PLAYER, OBSTACLE, COLLECTIBLE}

var grid_size = Vector2(16,16)
var grid = []

onready var Obstacle = preload("res://scenes/Obstacle.tscn")
func _ready():
    # Creates grid array of grid_size
    for x in range(grid_size.x):
        grid.append([])
        for y in range(grid_size.y):
            grid[x].append(null)
    print(ENTITY_TYPES)
    # Create obstacle positions array
    var positions = []
    # create 5 obstacles
    for n in range(5):
        # random positions constrained to grid_size
        var grid_pos = Vector2(randi() % int(grid_size.x),randi() % int(grid_size.y))
        #check random posisitions not already in array before adding new one
        if not grid_pos in positions:
            positions.append(grid_pos)
    for pos in positions:
        var new_obstacle = Obstacle.instance()
        new_obstacle.position = (map_to_world(pos) + half_tile_size)
        grid[pos.x][pos.y] = ENTITY_TYPES.OBSTACLE
        add_child(new_obstacle)

func is_cell_vacant(pos, direction):
    # Return true if cell is vaccant, else false
    var grid_pos = world_to_map(pos) + direction

    # world Boundaries
    if grid.pos.x < grid_size.x and grid_pos.x >= 0:
        if grid.pos.y < grid_size.y and grid_pos.y >= 0:
            #return true if grid[grid_pos.x][grid_pos.y] == null else false
            return grid[grid_pos.x][grid_pos.y] == null
    return false


func update_child_pos(child_node):
    # Move a child to a new position in the grid array

    # Returns the new target world position of the child
    var grid_pos = world_to_map(child_node.position)
    grid[grid_pos.x][grid_pos.y] = null

    var new_grid_pos = grid_pos + child_node.direction
    grid[new_grid_pos.x][new_grid_pos.y] = ENTITY_TYPES.PLAYER

    var target_pos = (map_to_world(new_grid_pos) + half_tile_size)
    return target_pos
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving the error because you are exceeding the arrays elements.

To avoid it, either make the grid bigger or make it so that the player cannot leave the grid.

If you want the player to be able to leave the grid, then you will probably have to create an `if` condition:

```
if player_in_grid: grid[new_grid_pos.x][new_grid_pos.y] = ENTITY_TYPES.PLAYER.
```